# start activity by clicking notification android

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, start-activity

i have problem with starting my activity when click on notification...

```
public class MyNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(context, "notification", 25).show();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Test Notification")
            .setContentText("This is test notification ");
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
            myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent2);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}

}
```

whats wrong ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way

```
 PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
        myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity` use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`

```
 PendingIntent intent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
        myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

For more info go to http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/start-activity-once-notification-clicked.html